# backbone.js do something when event (vent) is complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, backbone.js

```
$('button').click(function(){
  App.vent.trigger("box:change");
});

App.BoxView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(options) {

    this.listenTo( App.vent, "box:change", this.alter ); // animate, etc.
  },

  ...

});
```

I have a main view, in wich i wish to do some changes when (and/or):

1. the event is processed by all my boxes
2. all my boxes done with some animations

can't wrap my head around this(long work day)... 
please help =) 
what is the better practice?

i'm looking for something like this:

```
App.MainView = Backbone.View.extend({
      initialize: function(options) {

        // when all the events are complete
        this.listenTo( App.vent, "box:change" ).onComplete( this.rearrange_stuff );

        // when all the animations are complete
        this.listenTo( App.animationBuffer, "box:fadeOut" ).onComplete( this.rearrange_stuff );

      },

      ...

});
```

update:
  and what if I have a long chain of events - complete - events - complete (not loop) in my application, what is the better way to set this queue?

Comment: Your `App.vent.trigger()` call is single threaded so all the handlers will have returned when `trigger` returns. The animations are where all the work is.

Comment: @muistooshort Yes, I can somehow collect the animations and use promise to set a callback for when ALL the animations are complete. But that also means that I need to have only animations (or setTimeouts) in my alter()...

Comment: Do you know how many boxes there are? You could make each box trigger an "I'm all done everything I'm doing" event of some sort at the end of the animations. Then, if you know how many boxes there are (`n`) when you call `trigger`, you can list for those custom events and do whatever needs to be done when you've received `n` of them.

Comment: @muistooshort That is what I am doing now, I am not comfortable with this approach, so I look for a different one...

Comment: Well, someone has to know how many animations are running or there's no way to know that they're all done.

Answer (score 0):

with jquery I found promise, just need to figure-out how i apply this to all my views..

http://api.jquery.com/promise/

(update)

For now, I've done it this way...
http://jsfiddle.net/Antonimo/YyxQ3/2/

```
App.vent = _.extend(Backbone.Events, {
    promise: function(name){
        if(typeof this._bills[name] === "undefined"){
            this._bills[name] = 0;
        } else {
            this._bills[name] ++;
        }
    },
    keepPromise: function(name){
        var that = this;
        setTimeout( function(){
            if(typeof that._checks[name] === "undefined"){
                that._checks[name] = 0;
            } else {
                that._checks[name] ++;
            }
            if(typeof that._bills[name] !== "undefined"){                    
                if( that._checks[name] >= that._bills[name] ){
                    that._checks[name] = 0; // reset
                    that._bills[name] = 0; // reset
                    that.trigger(name); // emit event
                }
            }

        }, 30);
    },
    _bills: {},
    _checks: {}
});

// usage:

alter: function() {
        App.vent.promise('some:event');
        // Animate, or not..
        App.vent.pay('some:event');
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution to this and found this plugin to Backbone that adds a "triggerThen" method to Backbone.Events and other Backbone objects which allows you to trigger an event and then call a function after all of the event listeners have completed.

https://github.com/bookshelf/trigger-then

It would be nice if there was an official Backbone solution to this though that used promises throughout the Backbone.Events framework.